# Converting a ParametricPlot parametric expression to a ContourPlot cartesian expression

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Using `ParametricPlot` I can plot a lemniscate expressed in parametric coordinates:

```
  ParametricPlot[1/(1 + Sin[t]^2) {Cos[t], Cos[t] Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 [Pi]}]
```

I want to find using Mathematica the equivalent cartesian expression and plot it using `ContourPlot` that I know to be:

```
ContourPlot[(x^2 + y^2)^2 == (x^2 \[Minus] y^2), {x, -1, 1}, {y,-1,1}]
```

Looking up among the MMA functions I wondered if  `CoordinateTransformData` or `TransformedField` could help me but none of them has the appropriate coordinate transformation :`"Parametric" -> "Cartesian"` which had me baffled.

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how much automatic solution you want.

```
eq = Thread[{x, y} == 1/(1 + Sin[t]^2) {Cos[t], Cos[t] Sin[t]}];
cont = Eliminate[eq, t] // Simplify
```

> ```
> y != 0 && x^4 + y^2 + 2 x^2 y^2 + y^4 == x^2
> ```

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@Last@cont, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes indeed! Your answer explains perhaps why `CoordinateTransform[ "Parametric" -> "Cartesian"...` has not been implemented in MMA.